# How do I create a C# program with arguments that you can right click a file and open with that C# program?

Tags: c#

How do I create a C# program with arguments that you can right click a file and open with that C# program?

```
namespace JV_Media_Player
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args == null)
                return;

            WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer windowsMediaPlayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

            windowsMediaPlayer.URL = args[0];
            windowsMediaPlayer.controls.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more a super user question really, as it's just a bit of poking stuff into the registry, maybe not even trhat if you're getting the user to always associate abc files with your app (something they must do with file associations themselves for security reasons)

Comment: Do I write the program the same way as command line arguments?

Comment: Which bit are you have problems with - creating a program that takes arguments - if so then there are plenty of examples online. How to associate a file type with a particular application - that is not a C# programming issue per se - you may be able to do this with the installer or manually.

Comment: Please share your issue, or just search a sample form in google

Comment: I just did one example for notepad++

Comment: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/18857/how-to-open-specific-files-in-different-folder-where-root-folder-might-be-varied-open-file-in-solution-is-my-temporary-solution/7 Sorry for splitting the comments. Accidentally hit done.

Comment: See code above.

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow doesn't really deal with the aspect of your question that surrounds making the necessary steps or registry changes to associate files with your program or add your program to the right click context menu. However, in a programming sense your main entry point to the app (usually called Main) takes an array argument and in that array will be all the parameters that were passed to your app. When explorer does an "open with" it passes the full path of the relevant file/s to your app:

```
class Program{
  static void Main(string[] args){

  }
}
```

If you were to compile this, associate .abc files with it then double click an .abc file in c:\temp\my.abc, then `args[0]` would be `"c:\temp\my.abc"`

It should be noted that if you selected 100 files and right clicked one of them and chose Open, explorer would launch your app 100 times with one file argument each time. It does not launch it once and pass 100 arguments. If you want one app instance to know all 100 items, you have to make your app single instance and have the 99 subsequent instances of your app communicate their argument to the first instance then quit. This was always easiest, classically, by importing the Vb.Net provisions(referencing the relevant vb helper dlls) for doing this

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: I'll just get my crystal ball out then.. ;) Joking aside, "it didn't work" is a nearly completely useless phrase on StackOverflow - tell us what result you see compared to the result you're expecting (we'll be able to infer that it didn't work from your report) - we need much more detail to be able to help you

Comment: Lol. It didn't palsy the .wav file when I right clicked that file and open with JV Media Player. See my code above.

Comment: Im not familiar with this lib, but one problem could be that play() doesn't block execution of your program thread until the file finishes playing? Maybe your app start to play() then immediately just quits and disposes of the media player because the code runs out of the end of the Main. Perhaps a simpler `Console.Writeline("Got arg:" + args[0]);` would prove the concept working about how the args are passed

Comment: args[0] has the right file path

Comment: From https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/wmplibiwmpcontrols-iwmpcontrols-play--vb-and-c I presume I am correct: I don't think Microsoft would have implemented the play() command so that it blocks execution of the current thread, because they use it in a button click handler in that documentation; if play did block it would hang the entire ui when used in accordance with that example. As such, I assert that your media file might well be playing but then your program quits naturally a few milliseconds later. Make a GUI app or use a way to prevent the exit, like a console.Read